# 502 Bad Gateway | Gunicorn - ngnix - django

Tags: django, nginx, server, gunicorn

I wanted to that my dango app run in server and I tried with gunciron. When i run my app with gunicorn, server is working.
I mean

```
`# gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 myapp.wsgi`
```

is working

But if i disconnect with server, server is not working. So i used ngnix.

I followed this source https://github.com/satssehgal/URLShortnerDjango- . I did all them. I controlled my path but all path is right. What can i do for server work?

systemctl status nginx
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s2s8.png)

ps aux | grep php-fpm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyTgh.png)

ngnix.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
         include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##
        
         gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/x$
        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/myapp:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    keepalive_timeout 10;
    charset     utf-8;
    location /static/ {
        root /root/ayzguci/myapp;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/root/ayzguci/myapp/myapp.sock;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $5.105.5.140;
    }
        }
```

ps ax|grep gunicorn outout:

```
 1782 ?        Ss     0:00 /root/ayzguci/myenv/bin/python3 /root/ayzguci/myenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --timeout 1000 --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/ayzguci/myapp/myapp.sock myapp.wsgi:application
 1812 ?        S      0:00 /root/ayzguci/myenv/bin/python3 /root/ayzguci/myenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --timeout 1000 --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/ayzguci/myapp/myapp.sock myapp.wsgi:application
 1813 ?        S      0:00 /root/ayzguci/myenv/bin/python3 /root/ayzguci/myenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --timeout 1000 --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/ayzguci/myapp/myapp.sock myapp.wsgi:application
 1814 ?        S      0:00 /root/ayzguci/myenv/bin/python3 /root/ayzguci/myenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --timeout 1000 --workers 3 --bind unix:/root/ayzguci/myapp/myapp.sock myapp.wsgi:application
 1900 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto gunicorn
```

netstat -an|grep 8000 output:

```
root@localhost:~# sudo apt install net-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
net-tools is already the newest version (1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 72 not upgraded.
root@localhost:~# netstat -an|grep 8000
root@localhost:~#
```

Comment: What is output of this command `sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service`

Comment: sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service this command is working like ystemctl status nginx @AnkitTiwari

Comment: Hello @CanKURTHD check output of these commands `sudo journalctl -u nginx.service` & `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn.service`